# How do I create 7z files by date

Tags: command-line, date-time

How do I create a 7z file that had only files created after a specified date in it, using the command line?

Comment: Depends on the OS.

Comment: I don't think you can do this from 7z directly. You could use xcopy with the /d: parameter to copy the files to a folder and then use 7z with that folder. (assuming you are on windows)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a batch file that selects the files based on whatever criteria you wish, and then calls the 7z command line utility to compress these files as desired.